# How to change imported CAD file colors in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am new in ROS and THREE.js and have been trying to implement a web visualization for a robot movement using mqtt. I used this github project for that https://github.com/dersimn/robotWebView. So far the visualization works alright. However,i will like to change the color of the robot to make the movements even more visible. I tried changing the color of in the "THREE.MeshPhongMaterial" method in the "index.js" file but that did not help. Any idea on how to do this?

Update: This is the code i used

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xb5d3e7);

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
controls.update();

var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
scene.add(light);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
const loader = new URDFLoader(manager);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xce8821, specular: 0xce8821, shininess: 200});
var geometryLoader = new THREE.STLLoader();
//var geometryLoader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var myrobot = null;

loader.load('urdf/iiwa14/urdf/iiwa14.urdf', {}, robot => {
    myrobot = robot;
    console.log('complete', robot);

    scene.add(robot);
}, { loadMeshCb: (path, ext, done) => {
    geometryLoader.load(path, geometry => {
        console.log(path);
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        mesh.castShadow = true;
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    //scene.add(mesh);
        done(mesh);
    });
}});

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
animate();

// MQTT
var mqttUrl = 'ws://MyIPAdress:portNumber/mqtt';
var clientId = 'webui_'+Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,15);
console.log('MQTT conenct to', mqttUrl, clientId);
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(mqttUrl, clientId);
client.onMessageArrived = function(recv) {
    let topic = recv.destinationName;
    let message = JSON.parse(recv.payloadString);

    console.log(topic, message);

    myrobot.joints.iiwa_joint_1.setAngle(message[0]);
    myrobot.joints.iiwa_joint_2.setAngle(message[1]);
    myrobot.joints.iiwa_joint_3.setAngle(message[2]);
    myrobot.joints.iiwa_joint_4.setAngle(message[3]);
    myrobot.joints.iiwa_joint_5.setAngle(message[4]);
    myrobot.joints.iiwa_joint_6.setAngle(message[5]);
    myrobot.joints.iiwa_joint_7.setAngle(message[6]);
};
client.onConnectionLost = function() {
    console.log('mqtt disconencted');
};
client.connect({onSuccess:function() {
    console.log('mqtt conencted');

    client.subscribe('kuka/status/1/currentJointPosition');
}});
```

Comment: Can you please share your code that shows how you change the material's color?

Comment: Thanks, i updated my post with the code

Comment: Um, can you please show the line where `robot.material.color` is changed? According to your post, you want to change the color value of exactly this material, right?

Comment: I tired changing the color by changing the value of the parameter "color" in MeshPhongMaterial(). I didn't use the line robot.material.color for that.

Comment: Can you give it a try? It seems the newly created instance of `MeshPhongMaterial` is the material for a different geometry loaded with `STLLoader`.

Comment: I just gave it a try that but still no change.

Comment: I just found a way around it. I used dae files from https://github.com/ros-industrial/kuka_experimental/tree/indigo-devel/kuka_lbr_iiwa_support/meshes/lbr_iiwa_14_r820 as my visual mesh instead of the stl files and changed the Loader from STLLoader.js to ColladaLoader.js and this got me the right colors. So this topic can be marked as solved. I would still be interested to know why this didn't work with stl